# Removing the space between header and nav on Protostar

Tags: templates, template-override

I use Protosar template on Joomla.

I have tried for days now and I can't figure out how to remove the space/padding/margin between header tag and nav tag. I have done everything including zeroing margin and padding for the "header" and "navigation" classes but so far it hasn't worked. Any idea?

Comment: You can use negative margins for the nav tag. For example `.navigation{margin-top: -20px;}`

Answer (score 1):

You have for your header a `-20px` value for the top attribute. This causes the header to go up `-20px`, creating this extra space.

This is located in `templates/protostar/template.css` on line **14113**

Now, removing this `top: -20px;` will give you an extra space on top of the header. If you don't want this, then you have to adjust the padding for the container class - `templates/protostar/template.css` on line **14169**.

```
.body .container {
  background-color: white;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:20px;   **/* Change this to padding: 0 20px 20px; */**
...
}
```

Change padding to `padding: 0 20px 20px;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the time you put into this. I appreciated it.

Comment: @agahi - If this answered your question, please accept it by clicking the "tick" icon on the left hand side.